# Disable link to same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm looking for a best practice on how to disable a link that would redirect to the same page with jquery/ jquerymobile.

For example if I'm on the hompepage and there's a link pointing to homepage, it should not even refresh the page.

Code of my link:

```
<a href="Homepage.aspx" rel="external">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with jquery/jquery mobile to know if this is a best practice, but it should work.

```
$("a").each(function(){
   if(window.location.href==this.href)
     this.onclick=function(){return false};
});
```

Comment: It does the job as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Totally untested, but depending on how your code is written this could work.

```
$('a').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') === window.location.pathname) 
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        // Alternatively: $(this).attr('href','#');
});
```

Comment: This almost did the job, but my link, which is a navbar button, keep the click down style after being clicked.
It should be working for a regular link.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the current URL with `window.location.href` and extract the **page name**.

Then, you can iterate on each link and append behaviour for link that have the same href value as the current page value

```
var currentPage = ....// extract the page from window.location.href

$('a').each(function(index, element) {

    var currentA = $(this);
    if (currentA.attr('href') == currentPage) {
        // Append a listener on the click event that will return false
        // and stop the default behaviour
        currentA.on('click', false);
    }

});
```

Note: setting false as the handler function is the same as creating a anonymous function that return false, and is again the same as creating a function that call `event.stopPropoagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var a = document.getElementsByTagName("A"), b = 0; b < a.length; b++) {
    if (a[b].href === window.location.href.split("#")[0] && a[b].hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var c = 0; b < a[b].childNodes.length; c++) {
            a[b].parentNode.insertBefore(a[b].childNodes[c].cloneNode(!0), a[b]);
        }
    }
}
```